# Ошибка с Telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я хочу юзать его на версии 3.6.9 но в инете почекал надо 3.7, обновить не могу тк у меня VPS серв, подскажите те что то можно сделать?

```
    import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

def send_sticker(chat_id, file_id, reply_to_message_id):
    # Отправляем стикер в ответ на сообщение
    pack_id = 'ZOV_0'
    stickers = bot.get_sticker_set(pack_id).stickers
    if len(stickers) > file_id:
        bot.send_sticker(chat_id, stickers[file_id].file_id, reply_to_message_id=reply_to_message_id)
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, "В этом стикер-паке нет стикеров.")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_handler(message):
    # Получаем информацию о группе, в которой запущен бот
    group_info = bot.get_chat(message.chat.id)
    group_name = group_info.title

    # Отправляем сообщение с приветствием и информацией о боте
    message_text = f"Привет! Я бот-помощник, созданый для группы {group_name}."
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message_text, parse_mode='HTML')

# Обработчик новых участников
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def handle_new_chat_members(message):
    for member in message.new_chat_members:
        # Отправляем сообщение с приветствием
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, {}! Добро пожаловать в группу \"{}\"!".format(member.first_name, message.chat.title))

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.startswith('+'))
def handle_message_plus(message):
    # Отправляем сообщение с благодарностью
    bot.reply_to(message, "Спасибо за помощь!\nДержи медальку: ")
    # Отправляем стикер в ответ на сообщение пользователя
    send_sticker(message.chat.id, 2, message.message_id)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.startswith('Спасибо за помощь'))
def handle_message_pomosh(message):
    # Отправляем сообщение с благодарностью
    bot.reply_to(message, "Большое Вам спасибо!\nПримите медаль: ")
    # Отправляем стикер в ответ на сообщение пользователя
    send_sticker(message.chat.id, 1, message.message_id)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.startswith('Спасибо за доставку'))
def handle_message(message):
    # Отправляем сообщение с благодарностью
    bot.reply_to(message, "Большое Вам спасибо!\nПримите медаль: ")
    # Отправляем стикер в ответ на сообщение пользователя
    send_sticker(message.chat.id, 3, message.message_id)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["left_chat_member"])
def left_chat_member_handler(message):
    member_name = message.left_chat_member.first_name
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{member_name} покидает нас, к сожалению не смогли удержать участника {member_name}, надеемся что {member_name} к нам вернется")

# Запускаем бота
bot.polling()
```